# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

When I run the Entitfy framework core command `add-migration MyMigrationName` in a class library I get the following error

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Funny thing there is no reference in my application to Abstractions.

Here is my csproj

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
      <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
      <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
      <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
      <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net452</TargetFramework>
      <AssemblyName>MyProjectName</AssemblyName>
      <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
      <PackageId>MyProjectName</PackageId>
      <NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>1.6.0</NetStandardImplicitPackageVersion>
      <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
      <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
      <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
      <RootNamespace>MyProjectName</RootNamespace>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </None>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.5.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="1.1.2" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Collections" Version="4.3.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Linq" Version="4.3.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.3.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Threading" Version="4.3.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net452' ">
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get NuGet to add the appropriate binding redirects to class library projects, you need to add the following to your `*.csproj` file.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Worked for us, but how does that work under the hood ?  
We had a similar issue where we were using AspNetCore.Identity alongside another EFCore migration project, and for some reason, when running `Update-Database` from the PCM, it would look for System.Data.Sql v4.1.X.X, while EFCore comes bundled with System.Data.Sql v4.3.X.X  
  
Why would it use wrong bindings in the first place?