# Azure Durable function. Framework tries to load old version of assembly

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

When I try to run my durable function I get this error:

> A ScriptHost error has occurred.
>
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask: Could not load file or
> assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=1.0.4.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The error even persists if I try to deploy to Azure.

Currently my NuGet package for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask has a dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions for version >= 1.1.2.0. This is also the version I can see in my project.

I've tried to delete the bin folder and uninstall/install Visual Studio 2019, but no luck so far.

I'm fairly certain that it is a local issue on my PC since I asked my colleague to pull the code and run it, and there were no issues

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907819/microsoft-aspnetcore-hosting-abstractions-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the).

Comment: @FrankGong Thanks for your suggestion, the solution from that changed nothing for me

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're using the old version for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask. The current one is version 2.2.2

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask -Version 2.2.2
```

Comment: Correct, I am currently on 1.8.6, as I am trying to run a V1 durable function. DurableTask version 2+ is not compatible with functions V1

Comment: nothing works on v1 anymore. You should upgrade to v2/v3

Comment: I'd love to, but as always there are constraints. The function uses assemblies that is not .NET Core compatible

Comment: I've been there. Honestly, you'll fix this and other part will break due dependency on specific version of packages. The only possible solution without rewriting on .net core is: move everything to Azure Container Instances and use your Azure Function to Trigger it